# How to wait for Feature effects to register before a component in the root module dispatches an action?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have `EffectsModule.forFeature([..., abcEffects, ...])` in my lazy-loaded module (`config.module.ts`) and `EffectsModule.forRoot([])` in my bootstrap app module (`app.module.ts`).

Upon the initialization of my app.component, I dispatch an action (defined along with my lazy-loaded module) to do some initialization tasks.

Somehow the effects from the lazy-loaded module are not registered by the time the action is dispatched.

[image]

Is there a way to wait for the feature effects to register before dispatching actions?

Or perhaps some way to check whether the effects have been loaded before sending the action to the effect/reducer?

Comment: should that effect really be lazy loaded if you need to dispatch an action from app.module?

Comment: Why not just dispatching that action from the module that hosts the effect? Or even use the startWith operator inside the effect?

Comment: Well, the way I have structured my application is that app.component is a container for root and initializes certain things. It's just the one related action that I need to dispatch really.

Comment: In my opinion, if from the root of your app, you want to wait for some module to be lazy loaded before doing anything... That module should not be lazy loaded. Now, if you really want to keep it lazy loaded, you might just watch the part of the store that's supposed to be here once that module is loaded, and then only dispatch your action. But it feels like there's a deeper problem and this is not the right solution to go with

Comment: Firstly thank you for your comments. Also, yeah you make a fair point there. I was trying to minimize refactoring while still maintaining the benefits of separating concerns into modules.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of knowing when your effects are initialized, but isn't being released yet - [docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#update_effects).

```
@Effect()
init = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<UpdateEffects>(UPDATE_EFFECTS)
  filter(action => action.effects.includes('SomeEffectsClass')),
  map(action => ...)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could implement the effects lifecycle **OnInitEffects**

Example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInitEffects } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

@Injectable()
export class MyFeatureModuleEffects implements OnInitEffects {

    ngrxOnInitEffects(): Action {
        return someAction(...)
    }

}
```

And in the module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forFeature([MyFeatureModuleEffects])
  ]
})
export class FeatureModuleWithEffectsModule { }
```

Comment: This is a great answer!